# Impact on performance if APPLHEAPSZ is set too low

Tags: performance, configuration, db2

I have a server, with 4GB RAM, installed with DB2 10.5 and WebSphere Application Server 8.0. Recently we increase the RAM to 12GB to improve the performance. When I check the database config parameters, APPLHEAPSZ is set to 4096.

With the increase of RAM to 12GB, how will APPLHEAPSZ still set to 4096 VS APPLHEAPSZ set to AUTOMATIC impact on the performance?

Comment: Cross-posted at http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/104414/impact-on-performance-if-applheapsz-is-set-too-low

Comment: @mustaccio opps deleted from dba.stackexhange.com

Answer (score 0):

In production, generally application server and database server will be installed on separate machines with high configurations.

In your case, they both are installed on same machine. **APPLHEAPSZ refers to amount of application memory each individual database agent working for that application could consume**. This memory can change based on application's/database memory requirements/usage. Value of this parameter is set to Automatic from DB2 9.5version to avoid OOM erros on DB side. This value should be kept fixed only if,

1. You know DB agent memory requirement very well
2. You have very less memory and you need to limit memory usage to a fixed value. (As in your case, you have app server also installed on same server and to get enough memory to app server you need to limit usage of db server and vice versa)

If possible place app and DB server on separate machines and make the parameter as automatic(If not possible, keep a fixed value with right balance of "app memory + db memory APPLHEAPSZ + system memory")

In terms of performance, fixed value should give a good performance if DB usage is quite low. If DB usage goes in high than specified value in terms of memory then you face degradation in performance. Automatic value will serve best most of the time.

Comment: Application server usage is around 700MB - 800MB. I set the application server java heap size to 1GB. Database usage I noticed it can go up to 2GB sometime. Now with 12GB RAM, should be wise to set APPLHEAPSZ to Automatic?

Comment: If your application server usage is known and very less then (in short DB server is possible bottleneck) then it is wise to set that parameter to automatic

Answer (score 0):

Application heap size does not have any impact on the database performance. If an application runs out of its heap space it will simply roll back, it will not become slower.

Other memory consumers, primarily bufferpools and sort heap, do have impact on performance, so you may want to tune those instead.

You don't mention if your DB2 installation is 32-bit or 64-bit. Keep in mind that 32-bit applications cannot use memory over 4 GB, regardless of how much physical memory you have on your machine.

Comment: Bufferpools and sortheap is set to self tuning. Any other areas to tune? DB2 installation is 64 bits.